# Visual Studio Object Relational Designer not generating classes for stored procedures

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

This is my first project where I've needed to use Linq to SQL, so far I have generally found it easy to work with.   However, when adding stored procedures in the o/r designer, it doesn't generate the classes and I have no idea why.

I've tried a simple stored proc that just selects from a table with no input parameters, but still no joy.  I'm assuming I've overlooked a setting or something, but I can't find the solution.  Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schoolboy error.  I'd updated another table at the same time and hadn't noticed an error had crept in, so it wasn't updating anything never mind the stored procedures.  Once the error was fixed the code regenerated and the stored procedures were available.